# Copying relative formula with EPPlus not working

Tags: c#, excel-formula, epplus

I'm having trouble copying a formula from one cell to another using EPPlus. I want the copy to change the formula based on the cell position. I've tried using the copy function and I've tried copying the FormulaR1C1 property. Either way the formula gets corrupted.

To reproduce error copy this formula into cell(1,1) of an excel file named c:\test\in.xlsx =VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)

```
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace eptest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelPackage ep = null;
            ExcelWorksheet ws = null;

            ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("c:\\test\\in.xlsx"));
            ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            ws.Cells[1, 1].Copy(ws.Cells[2, 1]);
            //ws.Cells[2, 1].FormulaR1C1 = ws.Cells[1, 1].FormulaR1C1; //this doesn't work either

            ep.SaveAs(new FileInfo("c:\\test\\out.xlsx"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried copying the FormulaR1C1 property and it didn't work. See my above example, it's very easy to duplicate the my error. Only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a bug.  The issue is here:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/d09fd3516b01c9fc6d6500ab9ff0ed82a60fab7b/EPPlus/ExcelCellBase.cs#L988

Since there is a delta of 1 row between the source cell and the destination, the `UpdateFormulaReferences` is eventually called and tries to adjust the formula.  But the part of the formula that is `A:B` is the entire range which it does NOT correctly recognize and chews it up.  I will open up an issue on their GitHub page.

To get around it, do this:

```
//This does a literal string copy
ws.Cells[1, 1].Copy(ws.Cells[2, 1], ExcelRangeCopyOptionFlags.ExcludeFormulas);
ws.Cells[2, 1].Formula = ws.Cells[1, 1].Formula;
```

This avoids a call to that function and then does a literal copy of the forumla.  Cannot use the R1C1 since it also tries to adjust the formula.

Comment: I had to go back to Interop. All of the "non-excel" solutions had too many bugs. Even Microsoft's Open XML was buggy. For example this code doesn't work if you have too much data in your sheet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-delete-text-from-a-cell-in-a-spreadsheet

Comment: @Madison320  I see.  FWIW, turns out there is already a bug posted about it here (for the Epplus one): https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/512